# Creating maps for members using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm beginning AutoMapper and had a question. I came across sample code like this:

```
Automapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Author,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));
```

So this would let me convert a book to a book model, and then map the src to the src.author.name property because there was not a 1-1 mapping.

To confirm, it does *not* work in reverse on its own, meaning I now need to explicitly do this:

```
Mapper.Mapper.CreateMap<BookViewModel, Book>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Author.Name,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author));
```

Is that correct? So to further confirm, if I had 50 view models and views, I'd literally need 100 (one for the way in, one for the way out, plus any additional lines of code in the .ForMember expression)

Is this true? Is this a common practice (i.e. you could potentially see hundreds of lines of code to handle the field mapping back and forth for multiple DTOs with properties that do not match up 1-1)?

Comment: Starting with 6.1.0, AutoMapper supports richer [reverse mapping support](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateMap` creates a mapping for AutoMapper to use later when required. This is required only once in the lifetime of your Application. In order to make use of this mapping you have defined, you just need to call `Automapper.Map` method. Thus you don't have to create the mapping again and again.

Example:

```
var myBookViewModel = Automapper.Map<Book, BookViewModel>(myBook);
```

You are correct saying that defining a mapper for Book to BookViewModel will not make Automapper to create a mapper for BookViewModel to Book automatically for you. You have to create the mapper.

Comment: yeah i'd only have to make it once in my loading of the file, but i'm just saying that the very fact I'd have to have all that code like that in the startup.. ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

In essence *yes*, you'd need basically to specify both back and forth configurations to handle each DTO mapping. Without a deterministic pattern it is impossible to guess how the mapping would work between complex object when members' names are different, or when the properties you want are further within other objects, like in your example.

**However**, Automapper is fairly smart if you follow some basic patterns. In your case, if you change the DTO property name to `AuthorName` instead of `Author`, the `CreateMap` will properly map without having to specify the mapping manually (they call this "Flattening"). Automapper will [even map methods to properties if they follow a `GetProperty()` => `Property { get; set; }`  pattern](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening). Renaming your DTO properties to follow this pattern could probably save you a bunch of lines. Take a look at their [starters guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) for other ways to simplify your mappings.